# connected to psql docker container with psycopg2 but unable to read or write

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I'm trying to run a postgres db in a docker container, running a small python program with a class to call the db.

When I run code with a query it seems to work fine, but gives no results.
I can see that I in fact have hit the database because one of the tables have an id constraint, resulting in an error when I try to insert something that already exists.

Using the db from TablePlus works fine.

Code:

```
import psycopg2


class postgres():
    def __init__(self, db="foo", user="bar", password='baz', host='127.0.0.1', port=5432):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database=db, user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def query(self, query):
        self.cur.execute(query)

        # self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer, data varchar);")

    def close(self):
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()


db = postgres()
db.query("INSERT INTO test (id) values('test2')")
db.close()
```

results in:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/myname/projects/myproject/dataGathering/postgres.py", line 21, in 
db.query("INSERT INTO test (id) values('test2')")
File "/Users/myname/projects/myproject/dataGathering/postgres.py", line 11, in query
self.cur.execute(query)
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "id_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(test) already exists.
"""

Inserting something without a conflicting id raises no error but neither gives any results in the db. SELECT queries have the same faith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing:

`conn.commit()`

So your changes are not committed.

From here:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html

" close()

Close the connection now (rather than whenever del is executed). The connection will be unusable from this point forward; an InterfaceError will be raised if any operation is attempted with the connection. The same applies to all cursor objects trying to use the connection. Note that closing a connection without committing the changes first will cause any pending change to be discarded as if a ROLLBACK was performed (unless a different isolation level has been selected: see set_isolation_level())."

Comment: Thank for the insane fast and helpfull response!